# Cannor login using laravel 5 after run command

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

```
$ php artisan optimize  
$ php artisan route:cache  
$ php artisan config:cache Reply
```

I run these commands (based on some articles to optimize the web), but unfortunately after all this steps I cannot login anymore.

I don't know how to recover this. Please help me on this issue ..

Comment: when using edge broswer ..getting Token Mismatch Exception

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` please check second command I might be wrong syntatically